# Realm DB - Copy or update can only be called inside a transaction

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

I am building a notes app. This is the add note activity, It shows note successfully added while saving but after that raises the  **java.lang.IllegalStateException**
'''
class AddNotesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var titleED:EditText
private lateinit var descriptionED:EditText
private lateinit var saveNotesbutton:Button
private lateinit var realm: Realm

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_notes)

    //init views
    titleED = findViewById(R.id.title_Edittext)
    descriptionED = findViewById(R.id.description_Edittext)
    saveNotesbutton = findViewById(R.id.savenotesbutton)
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    //set onclick listener
    saveNotesbutton.setOnClickListener(){
        addNotesToDB()
    }

}
private fun addNotesToDB(){
    try {
        realm.beginTransaction()
        val notes = Notes()

        notes.title = titleED.text.toString()
        notes.description = descriptionED.text.toString()
        //notes.id = nextId
        realm.commitTransaction()

        Toast.makeText(this,"Notes added Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        startActivity(Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()

        //copy the transaction and commit
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(notes)

    } catch (e:Exception){

        Toast.makeText(this,"Failed $e",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

}
```

}
'''

Comment: Can you post your stack trace/logcat that points to the actual error? So other people can look further into the problem and help you. It's not clear where the error happened within your code, but mostly it's due to incorrect usage of Realm DB Transaction. With your stack trace/logcat, I may be able to help.

Comment: Shouldn't copyToRealmOrUpdate be inside a transaction block? I don't know what that function does, but it sounds like it's updating realm, so you might need to move your commitTransaction() call after realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(notes).